# Change Listview items from previous Listview

Tags: java, android, xml

Building my very first android app. I have successful been able to call an image and text block from a public class. So,

In DetailFragment, I have this:

```
public class DetailFragment extends ListFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Inflating the layout country_details_fragment_layout to the view object v */
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, null);

    /** Getting the textview object of the layout to set the details */
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.country_details);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.disco);
   // ListView lines = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.country_list);

    String[] myList = new String[] {"Hello","World","Foo","Bar", "New"};


    /** Getting the bundle object passed from MainActivity ( in Landscape mode )  or from
     *  CountryDetailsActivity ( in Portrait Mode )
     * */
    Bundle b = getArguments();

    /** Getting the clicked item's position and setting corresponding details in the textview of the detailed fragment */
    tv.setText("Details of " + Country.name[b.getInt("position")]);
    img.setImageResource(DiscoImage.flags[b.getInt("position")]);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ??);
    setListAdapter(adapter);


    return v;
}
```

Country.java returns this info fine:

```
public class Country {

/** Array of countries used to display in CountryListFragment */
static String name[] = new String[] {
        "BEYONCÉ","4","I Am... Sasha Fierce", "B'DAY", "Dangerously In Love"
};
}
```

Discoimage.java returns this fine:

```
 public class DiscoImage {
 static int[] flags = new int[]{

    R.drawable.ic_beycd,
    R.drawable.ic_4c,
    R.drawable.ic_cdiam,
    R.drawable.bdaycd,
    R.drawable.dilcd,
   };


    }
```

At this point, when you click on list item from the previous view, the image in the next view changes and so does a Textview.

I am wondering, how do I do this with a list view? Make a java file with a string but how will the data be laid out and how will it be called via

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NameofJavaClass.flags[b.getInt("position")]);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a custom ArrayAdapter.

To do so you must do 2 things.

1) Create the layout you want to be shown in each item on the view, and save it as an xml file in the layout folder.

2) Create a subclass (it can be inner) of ArrayAdapter which implements the following two methods: 1; `<SUBCLASSNAME>(Context context, int resource, item[] itemList) { super(context, resource, itemList); }`  2; `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` which must return a view.

A great video example of this can be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRANgDgM2Zg . Also if you are not using a inner class as he does, make a classwide LayoutInflator (e.g `private LayoutInflater inflater;`) object and assign it in the constructor (first part of #2) like this `inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out. I'm a tad bit confused. It was easy to change the the textview and imageview with strings and I would like to do that for a listview. I have a regular adapter that calls regular strings to the listview but i'd like it to change like the imageview and textview change.

Comment: you can make a add data to the adapters internal list and call notifyDataChanged(); or you can just create and assign a new adapter. both should work.

Comment: I have made a custom Adapter like you said. I'm able to fetch data from it now, with switch statements. Everything is still the same :( 
public class AnotherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public AnotherAdapter(Context context, int songname, int label, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.songname, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

Comment: please explain. Can you update the listview or not. or am i just tottaly off about your problem

Comment: I cannot. I'm not sure how to lay out the information as strings but for listview.

Comment: So, I put         int position = b.getInt("position");
then added a switch position statement and it seems to work. I'm amazed, haha. Thanks for your help.